# How to add selected items in an NSTableView using Cocoa Bindings?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I have two NSTableViews bonded to two NSArrayControllers using Cocoa Bindings. The NSArrayControllers are bonded to the NSManagedObjectContext and populated with NSManagedObjects from the persistent store coordinator.

Is it possible to bind a Label below to the sum of some items in the NSTableViews (the ones checked) using Cocoa Bindings and KVC? How? And how to make the sum with using Cocoa Bindings?

I can do all the work (and did it) using the NSTableViewsDataSource (and Delegate) protocols.
But I want to explore KVC & Bindings and don't know how to do this or where to read from.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With bindings you can make use of KVO array/set operators like @sum or @count. Yet, this only works for a whole array or set. From your description I understand, you have some elements within the array that have a checkbox which is checked? Only from these elements a sum should be calculated?

If so I see no way using bindings alone without code. You could calculate a sum for selected objects via bindings, though. By binding to the arrayController.selectedObjects.myKey.@sum for example.

Comment: Thanks a lot Volker, I used the datasource and delegate protocol to calculate them, as I said in my question. Is there any guide (book) I can use to expand my self in Cocoa?

Comment: There are quite many books available. I can recommend Cocoa Programming for Mac OS X by Aaron Hillegass. Also, to understand the design and some basic principles of Cocoa better, you may take a look at Kochans Programming in Objective-C 2.0 and especially at Buck & Yacktmans Cocoa Design Patterns.

Comment: I'd already read the two first books, Cocoa Programming for Mac OSX and Programming in Objective-C 2.0. The last one I haven't read. Thanks!